# Excluding time period over a month

Tags: sql, plsql

I have to get the results over a month excluding the time period each day. I have following query so far

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
  DECLARE
  CURSOR login_hist
  IS
   SELECT
     login_id, insert_date
   FROM
      Login_history
      where to_char(insert_date,'DD-MM-YY:HH:MM:SS') > '12-Mar-10'

    ORDER BY
      insert_date DESC; 
  BEGIN
   FOR cur IN login_hist
   LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( cur.login_id || ': $'      ||to_char(cur.insert_date,'DD-MM-YY:HH:MM:SS') );
    END LOOP;
  END;

-- Excludig hours 10:00am till 15:00 pm over a period of month
```

Comment: `to_char(insert_date,'DD-MM-YY:HH:MM:SS') > '12-Mar-10'` doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Won't the left side will be greater than the right side, if only the day portion of the left is greater then the right? E.g. '16-01-01:00:00:00' > '12-Mar-10'. Apart from that, the formats don't match. That is even in their precision, let alone the month being numeric on one an abbreviation on the other. Why not comparing using "the right" data type, hence `insert_date > to_date('12-Mar-10', 'DD-MON-YY')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the `:HH:MM:SS` from your where clause.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
CURSOR login_hist
IS
 SELECT
   login_id, insert_date
 FROM
  Login_history
  where to_char(insert_date,'DD-MM-YY') > '12-Mar-10'
 ORDER BY
  insert_date DESC; 

BEGIN
 FOR cur IN login_hist
 LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( cur.login_id || ': $' ||to_char(cur.insert_date,'DD-MM-YY') );
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your where clause to this:

```
where to_char(insert_date,'hh24:mi:ss') < '10:00:00'
AND to_char(insert_date,'hh24:mi:ss') > '15:00:00'
```

`MM` stands for month and `mi` stands for minutes